# Get values from aggregate method into NA values from other column condition in R

Tags: r, aggregate, na

I was trying to fill NA values from column 'Income' with the mean of the column based on the gender column, so if 'M' has a NA value, insert one from the mean of all 'M' people (except NA values):

```
    GENDER|INCOME
         M|     1
         M|     2
         M|     3
         M|    NA
         F|     4
         F|     4
         F|     5
         F|    NA


    GENDER|INCOME
         M|     1
         M|     2
         M|     3
         M|     2
         F|     4
         F|     4
         F|     5
         F|  4.33
```

I tried the aggregate method but it gives you a list that, if I try to input in my dataset, it gives me an error in order to write a CSV. It works perfectly to get the values, but I don't know how to input these values but manually.
This is my code so far:

```
df$INCOME[is.na(df$INCOME)] <- aggregate(.~df$GENDER, df, FUN = mean, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Where did `4.66` (for Female) come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we want the `mean` to fill the missing values (`NA`) for each 'GENDER', then use `na.aggregate` from `zoo` which does this automatically (`FUN` by default is `mean`)

```
library(zoo)
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% 
  group_by(GENDER) %>% 
  mutate(INCOME = na.aggregate(INCOME)) %>%
  ungroup
```

---

Or another option is to `replace` the `NA` elements with the `mean`

```
df %>%
   group_by(GENDER) %>%
   mutate(INCOME = replace(INCOME, is.na(INCOME), 
        mean(INCOME, na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
 ungroup
```

---

`aggregate` returns a `data.frame` of summarised value columns and the group column.  Thus, assigning on the `NA` elements with the whole data.frame may not work i.e. we need to extract the column

```
df_mean <- aggregate(INCOME ~ GENDER, df, FUN = mean,
   na.rm = TRUE, na.action = NULL)
df_mean
   GENDER   INCOME
1      F 4.333333
2      M 2.000000
df_mean$INCOME
[1] 4.333333 2.000000
df$INCOME[is.na(df$INCOME)] <- df_mean$INCOME
```

Extracting the `INCOME` column and assign could be buggy approach because

1. the 'GENDER' grouping may be in a different order than in the original data
2. the number of `NA` for each 'GENDER' could be potentially different

Therefore, an option is also to `merge` the summarised data and then change the values based on the `NA` elements

```
transform(merge(df, df_mean, by = "GENDER"), 
   INCOME = ifelse(is.na(INCOME.x), INCOME.y, INCOME.x))[c('GENDER', 'INCOME')]
  GENDER   INCOME
1      F 4.000000
2      F 4.000000
3      F 5.000000
4      F 4.333333
5      M 1.000000
6      M 2.000000
7      M 3.000000
8      M 2.000000
```

Comment: Thank you very much @akrun. Since yesterday, I had many problems with all of your answers. Not because they were bad, but compiling errors. I had problems with the '= unexpected error'. I installed some packages, then another error appeared. Now, apparently, worked. That's the way the cookie crumbles in the coder life... Thank you very much akrun :)

Comment: @IgnacioSuch No problem.  The `base R` solution with `merge` should have worked.